# Fourier transform $h(t) = e^{-2(t-1)}u(t-1)$

Tags: fourier-transform

I try to compute the Fourier transformation of $$h(t) = e^{-2(t-1)}u(t-1)$$
I was looking at the general rule $$e^{-at}u(t) \Rightarrow \frac{1}{a+j\omega}$$ which would lead me to the following

$$h(t) = e^2e^{-2t}u(t-1)$$
$$H(\omega) = e^2\frac{1}{2 + i\omega}e^{-i\omega} = \frac{e^{2-i\omega}}{2+i\omega}$$

I was wondering if that is correct? Also is there any good way to plot its magnitude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$\mathscr{F}\{h(t)\} = H(\omega)$$
It's easy to prove $$\mathscr{F}\{h(t-t_0)\} = e^{-j\omega t_0}H(\omega)$$
As you said $$\mathscr{F}\{e^{-at}u(t)\} = \frac{1}{a+j\omega} \ ,\ \ \ \ \ \Re\{a\} \gt 0 $$
Put $a = 2$ $$\mathscr{F}\{e^{-2t}u(t)\} = \frac{1}{2+j\omega} $$
Then $t_0 = 1$ and we got $$\mathscr{F}\{e^{-2(t-1)}u(t-1)\} = \frac{e^{-j\omega }}{2+j\omega}$$

This could be easily verified by [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral_%28-%E2%88%9E%29%5E%E2%88%9E%20%28e%5E%28-2%20%28t%20-%201%29%29%20%CE%B8%28t%20-%201%29%29%20e%5E%28-i%20%CF%89%20t%29%20dt%20%3D%20-%28i%20e%5E%28-i%20%CF%89%29%29%2F%28%CF%89%20-%202%20i%29).

**Edit:** The answers are the same $$ \frac{-j e^{-j \omega}}{\omega - 2 j} = \frac{j}{j}\frac{-j e^{-j \omega}}{\omega - 2 j} = \frac{e^{-j\omega }}{2+j\omega}$$

And the magnitude is

$$|\frac{e^{-j\omega }}{2+j\omega}| = \frac{|e^{-j\omega }|}{|2+j\omega|} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 + \omega^2}}$$
Because $$|e^{-j\omega }| = |j\sin(-\omega) + \cos(-\omega)| = \sqrt{\sin^2(\omega) + \cos^2(\omega)} = 1$$
And $$|2+j\omega| = \sqrt{2^2 + \omega^2}$$

Comment: Thanks. Do you apply the timeshift only once because it is t—1 for both terms?(last step). Also WA shows a slightly different result

Comment: @Chris Yes, that's right. The answers are indeed equal, see the edit please.

Comment: Superb thank you. How would you compute the magnitude? I would expect it to be $\sqrt{\left(\frac{cos(\omega)}{2+j\omega}\right)^2+\left(\frac{sin(\omega)}{2+j\omega}\right)^2}$

Comment: @Chris I added that, take a look.

Comment: oh interesting although I don't understand how to get from step2 to step3 on the magnitude

Comment: @Chris Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes for the numerator yes. But why does $j$ disappear in the denominator?

Comment: @Chris Because of the definition for the magnitude.